# parse XML with JavaScript when tag names are the same at multiple levels

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<section food="Fruit">
  <desc>Fruits of the World</desc>
  <fruit>
    <name>grapes</name>
    <desc>grow on vines</desc>
    <fruit>
      <name>seeded</name>
      <desc>seeded grapes</desc>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
      <name>seedless</name>
      <desc>no seeds</desc>
      <fruit>
        <name>seedless Concord blue</name>
        <desc>deep blue without seeds</desc>
      </fruit>
      <fruit>
        <name>seedless Concord red</name>
        <desc>rose colored without seeds</desc>            
      </fruit>
    </fruit>
  </fruit>
</section>
```

I'm trying to parse an XML file (using JavaScript) with a rather complicated nesting.  The sample provided is a snippet of what I am referring to. The basic problem is that the tags at multiple levels have the same name, e.g. "fruit" in the sample.  I need to be able
to extract information specific to a nesting level, and not just `getElementsByTagNames("fruit")`. In other words, referring the sample above, the tag name "fruit" is nested 3 deep-- my goal would be to extract, say, only the second level "fruit" information.

How can I best accomplish this?  I imagine I would need to refer to the parent/child relationships between the nodes, but I am unsure how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath, which allows you to select elements using a full or partial path to the element you wish to use. For example:

```
/section/fruit/fruit/fruit[1]/name
```

will return the name of the first of the two `fruit` nodes found at that level ('seedless Concord blue'). Using `fruit[2]` you will find the other node.

You can retrieve any node:

```
/section/fruit/fruit[2]/desc
```

returns 'no seeds', and

```
/section/@food
```

returns 'Fruit' (the contents of the `food` attribute in `section`).

You can evaluate XPath expressions using `document.evaluate()`:

```
var fruitName = document.evaluate("/section/fruit/fruit/fruit/name[1]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

There are many tutorials out there about XPath, and you can learn about how to run and configure the DOM `evaluate` method in its documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate) or [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-evaluate)

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting modern browsers you can use CSS-style selectors with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) (to get the first matching element) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) (to get all of them). To get only the 2nd level `<fruit>`(s) you'd use the selector `section > fruit > fruit`:

```
var first2ndLevelFruit = document.querySelector("section > fruit > fruit")
console.log( first2ndLevelFruit.querySelector("desc").textContent );
// => seeded grapes

var all2ndLevelFruits = document.querySelectorAll("section > fruit > fruit");
Array.prototype.forEach.call( all2ndLevelFruits, function(fruit) {
  console.log( fruit.querySelector("desc").textContent );
} );
// => seeded grapes
//    no seeds
```

For older browsers, @helderdarocha's suggestion of XPath is a great one.